# Has anyone had success using PayPal SoftDescriptors?

Tags: paypal

Paypal provides access to a parameter called "SoftDescriptor" in a number of their payment request API calls, in the classic API (either NVP or SOAP).  In theory, this parameter lets you send transaction-specific data along with your request, which will be passed along to the buyer's credit card statement.

This parameter is available on at least:

- [DoCapture](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/api/docapture-api-operation-nvp)
- [DoReferenceTransaction](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/api/doreferencetransaction-api-operation-nvp)
- [DoExpressCheckoutPayment](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/api/doexpresscheckoutpayment-api-operation-nvp)

I cannot, for the life of me, get this to work.  None of these calls seem to set the softdescriptor for the initial descriptor (Which shows up in the bank statement while the charge is pending, before the payment posts).  I've been waiting a few days for the payments to post to see if it will change at that point, but I'm skeptical.

Has anyone successfully used the SoftDescriptor?  Did it require extra account setup?

Comment: Something tells me PayPal wants a bounty set before they will offer a response!

Answer (score 1):

This might be very late.
Soft Descriptors is supported only for US,UK and CA merchants.
Your account needs to be enabled for Soft Descriptor.You can contact Businesss/Customer Support to get this enabled.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/release-notes/merchant/PayPal_Merchant_API_Release_Notes_115/#softdescriptorforpro

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I know this is an old post, but I was looking for the same answer to the same question and I thought I would share what I found.

You should be able to [use the following link](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integrate/#2-set-up-a-payment) to move past this error. In my case, I had a comma after the wrong right curly brace. Just copy and paste the example, in the aforementioned link, and change the values to meet your needs.

And I am about to post my own question about why the transaction amount is considered invalid